# Environment variables null in new Visual Studio 2019 but not Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, visual-studio-2019

I downloaded and setup the newly released Visual Studio 2019 Professional and opened a solution I have been working on in Visual Studio 2017 Professional.

This solution contains 3 ASP.NET Core projects and 1 docker-compose project.

When starting debug session in 2019 I get a null reference exception on one line where I'm referring to my docker-compose environment variables.

However if I open the same solution in Visual Studio 2017 I don't get this null reference exception as the values are correctly read from the docker-compose.yml file.

I have looked over the setup of both versions of Visual Studio and don't appear to be missing anything.

```
// Create intance of item message handler
var container = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var _settings = container.GetService<IOptions<Settings>>().Value;

var itemListenerSettings = _settings.RabbitSettings.ListenerSettings.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == "ItemListener");
if (itemListenerSettings.Value != null)
{
  // Register item listener...
}
```

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  microserviceapi:
    image: microserviceapi
    container_name: ms
    build:
      context: ./MicroserviceApi
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      RabbitSettings:Hostname: "rabbit"
      RabbitSettings:Username: "user"
      RabbitSettings:Password: "pass"
      RabbitSettings:ReconnectionRetries: "10"
      RabbitSettings:ReconnectionTime: "1000"
      RabbitSettings:ListenerSettings__ItemListener__ExchangeName: "Imagine.ItemManagement"
      RabbitSettings:ListenerSettings__ItemListener__ExchangeType: "topic"
      RabbitSettings:ListenerSettings__ItemListener__QueueName: "foo.Item"
      RabbitSettings:ListenerSettings__ItemListener__RoutingKey: "item.*"
```

While running a debug session in Visual Studio 2019, calling `var _settings = container.GetService<IOptions<Settings>>().Value` I expect the property `RabbitSettings` of the variable `_settings` to contain the values from my docker-compose.yml file as it does in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: I'm thinking it must have something todo with the serialization of the environment variables. Maybe that has changed. I will look into that better in the following few days but until then I'm still using VS 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The environment variables contain the ':' characters. As documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#environment-variables-configuration-provider

... it's recommended to use double-underscore '__' instead of ':' in enviroment variable names in asp.net core. ':' works fine in VS 2017 solutions, but VS2019 needs double-underscore '__'.